# using the data from the post request

Tags: angularjs, post

I pass two dates to the post method thro controller.The service responses back with some data based on the given input. Im using `$scope.onGetData` to get the `data` from `post method`, inorder to display the final result but it is not going inside the `$scope.onGetData`. So the question is how to fetch the response data from the service and use it inside a controller, so that I can make use of it in my view.

Controller:

```
        $scope.computationList;

        $scope.onViewLoaded = function () {
            computationManagementService.getComputation($scope.onGetData);
        }

        $scope.onGetData = function (data,response,error) {
            $scope.computationList = data;

        }

       $scope.calculateInput=function(start,end,htmlValidation)
       {
           var date={'startDate':start , 'endDate':end};
           if(htmlValidation){
         computationManagementService.getComputation(date,function(err,response){
           console.log("pass thro controller");
       });
    }else{
        console.log("Validation Error");
    }
    }
});
```

Service:

```
myApp.factory('computationManagementService', function($http, settings){
    var ComputationServiceFactoryObj = {};    
    var _getComputation= function(date,callback){
       $http({
           method:'POST',
           url: 'localhost:/8091/date/computation',
           data: date
       }).success(function(data,response,config){
               callback(response);
               console.log(data); // data 
           }).error(function (data, status, error, headers, config){
                       if(callback) {
                        callback(error);
                        console.log(error);
                       }
       });
    }

    ComputationServiceFactoryObj.getComputation= _getComputation;
    return ComputationServiceFactoryObj;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use the post method's data to the view then you can try this method And it worked for me but not sure if it is correct way of using the service.

Service:

```
myApp.factory('computationManagementService', 
                          function($http, $rootScope, settings){
    var ComputationServiceFactoryObj = {};   
    var _getComputation=function(callback){
               var computationData=$rootScope.finalResult;
               if(callback != null){
        callback(computationData);
    }
    } 

    var _postComputation= function(date,callback){
       $http({
           method:'POST',
           url: 'localhost:/8091/date/computation',
           data: date
       }).success(function(data){
               callback(data);
               $rootScope.finalResult=data;
               console.log(data); // data 
           }).error(function (data, status, error, headers, config){
                       if(callback) {
                        callback(error);
                        console.log(error);
                       }
       });
    }

    ComputationServiceFactoryObj.getComputation= _getComputation;
    ComputationServiceFactoryObj.postComputation= _postComputation;
    return ComputationServiceFactoryObj;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Some good practices:

- using `ngResource` is always preferable to the raw `$http` service, except for rare cases when you need some complex configuration that `ngResource` can't handle (I can't think of such, though). Why? It forces you yo use promises.
- return promises from your service methods instead of passing callbacks. Using callbacks will force you to call `$digest` on your scope so that bingings are re-evaluated, which goes against the way angular works in general and may have negative performance impact as well.

In your case I'd modify the `_getComputation` method to simply return a promise:

```
var _getComputation = function(date) {
  return $http({
    method:'POST',
    url: 'localhost:/8091/date/computation',
    data: date
  });
};
```

In your controller:

```
computationManagementService.getComputation(date)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.someValue = response.someValue;
  }, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I'd rather avoid injecting `$scope` in controllers, and use the `ngController='MyController' as 'MyCtrl'` syntax instead and assign values that should be accessible by views to the controller instance.

Comment: Could you please elaborate - do you see something in the console, is there an error etc.

Comment: I just noticed your URL is malformed - shouldn't it read `localhost:8091/date/computation` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to use `.success` and `.error` methods in your service as they are not chainable, Use `.then` format instead. `.success/error` methods are deprecated in the latest Angular version 1.6.

Here is the [**Deprecation notice**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice) from Angular documentaion.

**In your service :**

```
var _getComputation= function(date,callback){
   return $http({
       method:'POST',
       url: 'localhost:/8091/date/computation',
       data: date
   }).success(function(data,response,config){
           callback(undefined, response);
           console.log(data); // data 
       }).error(function (data, status, error, headers, config){
                   if(callback) {
                    callback(error);
                    console.log(error);
                   }
   });
}
```

**In your Controller :**

```
computationManagementService.getComputation(date,function(err,response){
  console.log("pass thro controller");
  console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: Im able to post but there isn't any response from the service

Comment: Is there any other possibility

Comment: Yeah, your post will work but the way you are handling the success callback doesn't work. Can you try the way I've mentioned above and check ?

Comment: If the call is successful, maybe the server is not responding back with any data. Does the server responds with any data for this api ?

Comment: Can you check if there is any data in the response using browser inspector ?

Comment: The success callback in my code gave me response but when I tried your code there is no response. Is there any other way to use the response from the success callback to controller?. So that I can you it the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132672/discussion-between-suzo-and-jazzoria).